# root user is not working on create a login path through mysql config editor

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

root is a super user and all queries are running through it inside shell script. i wanted to change this process and created a login path through mysql config editor for another user say admin. but when ever i set this up my existing jobs are getting failed with error access denied for root@localhost. Wondering is there any connection of root as a super user with a login path, as if I set a login path i am getting access denied error when i remove that my queries are running fine. How to overcome this error?

Comment: Not sure what you're doing (what's a login path?) but MySQL users have nothing to do with system users.

Comment: Your question seems to be confusing. Please explain clearly. Because we aren't gonna research what may be your question

Comment: I am running all queries through root. now i wanted to replace this process as it's a security concern. so i have created a user as admin and set a login path for that user through mysql config editor as "mysql_config_editor set --login-path=client --host=server2.cloud.com –-port=3307 --user=admin –-password". when ever i put this command my queries are throwing error as "access denied for root@localhost", once i remove the login path its working fine. don't know how its impacting to root user. Is there any constraint of mysql config editor that root user with no password will not work.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_config_editor https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-config-editor.html is a command line tool to store credentials to access MySQL- Databases.

When storing credentials with a user, these are available for sudo commands, but not for root user!

**Default User**

```
$: mysql_config_editor set --login-path=zabbix --host=localhost -- 
 user=zabbix --password
$: mysql_config_editor print --login-path=zabbix
[zabbix]
user = zabbix
password = *****
host = localhost
```

**Default User with sudo**

```
$: sudo mysql_config_editor print --login-path=zabbix
[zabbix]
user = zabbix
password = *****
host = localhost
```

**Root User**

```
$ sudo su root
$ mysql_config_editor print --login-path=zabbix

Empty Output !!! We will set the config as root user

root@: mysql_config_editor set --login-path=zabbix
--host=localhost --user=zabbix --password 
Enter password: 
WARNING : 'zabbix' path already exists and will be overwritten. 
 Continue? : y
root@: mysql_config_editor print --login-path=zabbix
[zabbix]
user = zabbix
password = *****
host = localhost
```

**Long story, short outcome:**

You must set the credentials as user root to use them as root